# LAPTOP will not charge battery or run on AC power

Tags: power

I have a Toshiba satellite c655-s5049 that will not charge and will not run with the power cord plugged in.  The only way to use it is to charge the battery on a similar computer and use it on battery power.  I have replaced the dc plug, ac adapter, and the battery but it will not charge or run on AC power. Any suggestions before replacing the mother board?

Answer (score 2):

If it were on my bench, I'd re-examine the repair job that was done to replace the DC jack.  Now, with that particular DC jack...

[image]

The beauty of the design (since the A100 series... L100, etc) is that any damage to the jack doesn't actually damage the motherboard.  Unlike previous older designs which had the DC jack mounted right to the motherboard itself... and certain kinds of damage could rip/break the motherboard where the jack was mounted.  Also, technicians who were not careful could tear the tin collars out from the holes where the jack was mounted, causing the replaced jack not to make the proper contact on both sides of the motherboard (among other things).

Did you replace the jack?  Did Toshiba?  Was the entire assembly (pictured above) replaced, or was just the port replaced and jury-rigged onto the cabling?  The end looks like an easy-to-disconnect 4 contact plug, but it's actually not that simple to remove... and it is possible that when the port was replaced, this was damaged in the process.  Again... hard to say without having the unit on my bench.  For several model series after they instituted this design, the white plug end of this assembly didn't connect to a jack.  It was simply connected to 4 pins on the motherboard.  Toshiba did not move away from that design (to the best of my knowledge) so it is even possible that a technician who was not paying attention connected the plug backwards.  Ok... a very low probability, but still a possibility.

But... if the DC jack and cabling was replaced properly, the DC adapter has been replaced with one that supplies the proper voltage and amperage, and the battery has been replaced... that only leaves one more thing and you know what it is.  The Motherboard.

Toshiba recommends their [universal 75 watt adapter](http://www.toshibadirect.com/td/b2c/adet.to?poid=435061) (19V x 3.95 A) which means that the 65 watt adapters you can find around on Amazon and other places is probably closer to what the laptop came with, so unless you are trying some other brand of Universal Adapter with the absolute wrong tip, the adapter you have is probably alright.  In some cases, if you were using a 65 watt adapter and your system required 90 watts (or using a 90 watt and it required 120) you might see an issue with charging when you were using the laptop, but it would still charge when plugged in and turned off.  Just bringing that up.

Now, when you remove the battery, and plug the power adapter in, there are no LEDs on?  Not even for a fraction of a second?  No indication whatsoever that you just plugged a power source into the unit?

Seriously though... I'd have the job that was done for replacing the DC jack rechecked.  That will be far cheaper than replacing the motherboard... and if it tests out fine (with a multimeter applied to different parts of the board to make sure that power is flowing even if it's not turning on) then you know for sure it needs a new board.

Comment: Where's the picture from?

Comment: that one was from http://www.laptopacdcjack.com I chose it because I liked it over many of the other ones out there.

Comment: Thanks - I just wanted to make sure we credit the source properly.